# How to force redirect for a new account in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, registration

I want to force redirect on special page when a new account is created but it doesn't work. It always redirects to the WP dashboard.

```
function redirect_testtt($user_id) {
  wp_redirect('http://www.example.com/me');
  exit;
}
add_action('user_register', 'redirect_testtt');
```

How to force redirect for a new account please ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
// add action to after registration hook
add_action('user_register','after_reg');

// redirect users after registration
function after_reg() {
     wp_redirect('http://google.com');
     exit();
}
```